Alpha channel still blocking grease pencil layer (4.2.1)
I need some help, if possible.
I have a png image created with PS and imported as plane with alpha channel (Cycles).
I also have a grease pencil layer used to paint vegetation on the scene.
Problem is: the alpha channel (that makes transparency correct through the plane) is still blocking the grease pencil layer behind it. Basically the alpha channel is working for everything, but the grease pencil layer.
Any idea/workaround?
Thanks

When using Cycles, you have to tick the "Z Pass" option in the View Layers properties in order to work: the transparency will look correct in the rendered image, even if it doesn't show in the viewport (use Eevee during editing the scene, if needed).
Other ways you can try: use two different renders for GP and meshes, and use compositor to mix them.
Check also the location of the origin of the GP object and try to move it in an appropriate place (set the 3D cursor, then right click on the object > Set Origin to 3D cursor).
If the problem still persist, please upload your file here.


Thank you for your answer. Z pass was already on, but you are right> despite being not transparent in render view, it is actually transparent once rendered. Strange stuff. Have a nice day!
